# usepackage{multicol} gives undefined control sequence error

Tags: pdftex, multicol

I am trying to typeset two columns using the `multicol` package. I have made sure that the `.sty` style file available in my path. I even copied it my `pwd` just to make sure.

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
Column 1
\columnbreak
Column 2
\end{multicols}
```

But I still get the following error.

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
<argument> \multicol
```

When I remove the `\usepackage{multicol}` the document compiles fine so the error must be in in this.

It is as if this package is not installed on my system. But I have a full working tex distribution on my mac os x.  Here is the version info:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.29; using libpng 1.6.29
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04
```

What's going on in here?

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide a minimal file showing the problem.  The file most likely should start with `\documentclass`, include the package you load, and `\begin{document}` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: When I used `\usepackage{multicols}` instead of `\usepackage{multicol}` everything works. So I guess my question is resolved. However even the official documentation for `multicol` uses `\usepackage{multicol}`. Strange!!!

Comment: `\usepackage{multicol}` works fine for me. If it doesn't work for you but `\usepackage{multicols}` does something is **very** odd your system and you should really show a complete example and the log-file.

Comment: @minibuffer Did you download the package "by hand" and accidentally rename it?